# Alternative to update query having IN and NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table that has around 18000 records but, I am facing a performance issue.

Table name: `emp`

column name:

```
id VARCHAR(10),
status CHAR(1),
division VARCHAR(3)
```

Table 2 name : `emp2`

```
id VARCHAR(10),
status CHAR(1),
division VARCHAR(3),
code VARCHAR(3)
```

So, I am firing the following update query:

```
UPDATE emp
set status = 'X'
where status = 'Y'
and id NOT IN 
   (
   SELECT id from emp2 where id like 'e%'
   and division IN
         (
           SELECT DISTINCT division from emp2 where code in ('ABC','XYZ')
         )
   );
```

The query seems to be fine but is creating lots of performance issue. I googled to understand that `inner join` can be used instead of `IN` and `left join` can be used instead of `NOT IN`.

But I am finding it difficult to incorporate these in the query. So, I wanted to know if there is an alternative to this update query.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Can you better define "performance issue"? What's the exact problem you're observing and trying to solve? You should put in the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the exact structure of your tables as well, including any indexes that might be defined as those are often the root of performance problems.

Comment: You could execute that with the execution plan to make sure where exactly your query is having those performance issues. It would help us to help you. You are probably missing some index there...

Comment: @tadman "Performance issue" as in it is taking a lot of time to execute!!

Comment: @KimLage Would surely look into that and get back to you!!

Comment: Some people complain that 10ms is "a lot of time", so we need exact figures here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something akin to the following, but make sure you use the same query in a SELECT before running an update so you can spot check.

```
UPDATE emp
set status = 'X'
FROM EMP E
LEFT JOIN emp2 E2 on E2.id = E.ID AND E2.id like 'e%' AND E2.division in (SELECT DISTINCT division from emp2 where code in ('ABC','XYZ'))
where E2.id IS NULL
AND E.status = 'Y'
```

Spot Check

```
select E.id, E.status, 'X' AS ToStatus
FROM EMP E
LEFT JOIN emp2 E2 on E2.id = E.ID AND E2.id like 'e%' AND E2.division in (SELECT DISTINCT division from emp2 where code in ('ABC','XYZ'))
where E2.id IS NULL
AND E.status = 'Y'
```